# FIleNotFoundException error was generated at runtime

Tags: android, file, android-file

```
private void readFileFromSDCard() {
        File directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File file = new File(directory+"/HomeActivityLogs");
        //file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        if (!file.exists()) {

            FileWriter gpxwriter;
            try {
                System.out.println(" IN TRY Error");
                file.createNewFile();
                gpxwriter = new FileWriter(file);

                System.out.println(" file writer Error");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
            out.write("http://192.168.1.126/msfaws2_4/Service.asmx");
            System.out.println(" in url Error");
        ///    out.write("http://192.168.1.250/msfaws2_4/Service.asmx");
            out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                loginLog.appendLog("Exception in readFileFromSDCard() " + e.getMessage(),"MainActivity");
            }
        }

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Error");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            Constant.URL = builder.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    loginLog.appendLog("Exception in readFileFromSDCard() " + e.getMessage(),"MainActivity");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Please help me to solve this. It gives an error filenotfound with the filename
it creates dynamically from the web services, when the data was stored temporary and then retrieved from the activity.

Comment: did u add a premission in mainfest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add this permission in you `manifest.xml`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I provide the permision of internet and Write_external_storage also